# Caching external responses originated from google cloud functions

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using google cloud functions as my backend server. 
Some of my functions are generating requests to external API's. I need to cache the responses, and I wonder of the recommended way to do that in the cloudFunctions space. (Is there any google cloud service dedicated to this need?)

any tips guys?